# how to set an alternative path for loading a .net dll in the app.config file other than probing and codebase

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-assembly, app-config

I have the following situation: My application use a custom.dll. This custom.dll could be located in 2 places:

- Direct in the application directory
  or
- In a sub folder in the application directory

If the sub folder exists, i want to load the dll from the sub folder and if the sub folder doesn't exists i want to use the dll from the application folder.

I tried the following approaches:

- Using : This works fine, but the .net runtime search first in the application folder and if the dll is found it will never search in the sub folder.
- using <codebase version="x.x.x.x" href="subfolder\custom.dll>: The problem here is, if the sub folder doesn't exists, the application will fail and the application directory is never searched.

Is there any possibility in the "app.config" to search first in the sub folder and if the dll is not found than search the application directory.

I want to have a solution, which works with app.config and not programatically.

Comment: You describe an algorithm how to load. Such things are represented in code and not in configs. If you could do it in the app.config it would still be "programatically". Is the custom.dll managed or unmanaged?

Comment: @ralf it is a managed dll

Comment: The one thing that comes somewhat near to what you want is adding the probing path to the app.config where the framework should look (Additionally to the standard pathes).  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/probing-element